# JSON Schema for strict objects in an array

Tags: json, schema

I have created a JSON schema to validate a simple JSON file.  The good news is that it validates in the way that I intended, in that any number of booking elements can appear in any order, and no extra properties are allowed in each type of booking element.

Ideally I would like to remove the full list of possible properties in a bookingElement object (id, type, depair, destair, city) in the JSON schema, and just leave the oneOf lists, which show clearly which fields are allowed in each different type of element.

Can anyone provide a version of the schema without that full list that still applies the strict rules?

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "bookingElements": [
        {
            "id" : "00003",
            "type" : "flight",
            "depair" : "LHR",
            "destair" : "CDG"
        },
        {
            "id" : "00008",
            "type" : "hotel",
            "city" : "Paris"
        }
    ]
}
```

The schema is:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "bookingElements": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "depair": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "destair": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                },
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "depair": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "destair": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "city": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "bookingElements"
    ]
}
```

Ideally the JSON schema would look something closer to the following:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "bookingElements": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "depair": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "destair": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "object",
                        "additionalProperties": false,
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "city": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "bookingElements"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The braces weren't in the code blocks because your formatting was wrong - you need to indent *all lines*, not just the first, by four spaces (or use triple-backtick "code fences"). Select the code, hit the `{}` button or Ctrl-K.

Comment: This is quite useful for testing: [JSON Schema Validator](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you - edited!